# Amazon MWS API - single product update

Tags: php, api, amazon-mws

I want to update a single Amazon product's price or qty with an api call.

I know i can send a feed of one or multiple products, but is the another api call to send a single product and get an immediate response?

I also want an api call to GET my qty for sale on a single product. GetMyPriceForSKU  does not have qty.

anyone know which amaozn mws api & call to look in for this. I already looked through the mws dev pages and did not find anything.

Comment: i currently use the feeds and reports api. i want something faster for a single product instant info.

Answer (score 3):

Sending products to Amazon must go through feeds. Use the [Feeds API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html).  You'll need to create a feed of one or more products, submit the feed, and then query as to the status of the feed.  In my experience it takes a matter of a few minutes but I have seen a few thousand products take several hours.

To view your inventory, you'll need to use the [Reports API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/index.html) to request one of the [listings reports](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__ListingsReports)

Also, check out the [scratchpad](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/scratchpad/Scratchpad_WhatIs.html).  That's a great tool for trying out an operation with minimal resources.

Comment: i am aware of the feeds and reports api. i was hoping to have a simpler/faster option for a single product query or update...

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, they don't differentiate between a single product and multiple products.  It's just a feed to them and they process it when you're next in line.  But when I submit a single product in a feed, it usually gets processed in a matter of seconds.

Comment: i know there is an api to get my price for single item but not qty.